# SQL giving wrong results when filtering with certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database, teradata

Given that every product has a unique `PRODUCTID`.
`BATCH_DT` reveals the arrival time of every batch of goods.
The rule is that the price of the same kind of product, within the same batch, has to be the **same**. The prices of the same kind of product may **vary** in different batches.

Here is the syntax for this role:

```
PRODUCTID IN (
  SELECT PRODUCTID 
  FROM (
    SELECT PRODUCTID, 
      COUNT (distinct PRICE) AS countinGroup 
    FROM TABLE_WAREHOUSE_ 
    GROUP BY PRODUCTID, BATCH_DT 
    HAVING countinGroup > 1 
  ) x
)
```

However, when I apply this into the database, it gives me two products: CAF and HSRGF.

I think the codes are supposed to give me the products which have different price but in the same batch. However, when I filtering the results in Excel, it shows that the prices of CAF are the same.

Is there any way I am able to fix this?

sample data (the expected output should be like row 2 & 3):

```
Company | Effective date | e-status | Product | ProductID | payment | currency | Price | BATCH_DT
--------+----------------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+----------
2       | 20,190,831     | OP       | 001     | UF1       | 0       | HKD      | 144.7 | 8/31/2019
2       | 20,190,831     | OP       | 001     | UF1       | 0       | HKD      | 120   | 8/31/2019
4       | 20,190,831     | OP       | 001     | CAF       | 0       | USD      | 112.4 | 8/31/2019
5       | 20,190,831     | OP       | 006     | HKRSG     | 0       | CAD      | 99.3  | 9/16/2019
```

Comment: Please provide us with a sample set of data and your expected result.

Comment: @EternalHour Added as you suggested. Please click into the links. Thank you!

Comment: No pictures, thanks. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What do you mean by 'same kind of product'? Can there be more than 1 batch with the same batch_dt? Sample data as text would be useful to you.

Comment: edited as suggested. Thank you all. sorry it's my first time posing here.

Comment: @P.Salmon one BATCH_DT only corresponds to one batch. "same kind of product" means products share the same product ID.

Comment: Teradata or MySQL?

Comment: @dnoeth Teradata

Comment: And what exactly do you want to return? Only those *PRODUCTID, BATCH_DT* with different prizes (then your original Select fails because it returns all rows for a *product* if there's was a single bad batch)? Aggregated data (e.g. one row with min/max price) or all rows for a bad batch?

Comment: @dnoeth desired output should be same ProductID, Same Batch_DT but different value of product price.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that helpful to post sample data as HTML - much more useful as text. You could also improve your question by adding your desired output. Here's a model which illustrates what I think your question is

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(productid int, batch_dt date, price int);

insert into t values
(1,'2019-01-01',10),(1,'2019-01-01',10),(1,'2019-01-01',20),(2,'2019-01-01',10),
(1,'2019-01-02',10),(1,'2019-01-02',10),(1,'2019-01-02',10),(2,'2019-01-01',10);
```

You can test for distinct prices and print them using aggregation functionality

```
select batch_dt,productid, count(distinct price)  dp,group_concat(distinct price) prices
from t 
group by batch_dt,productid having dp > 1;

+------------+-----------+----+--------+
| batch_dt   | productid | dp | prices |
+------------+-----------+----+--------+
| 2019-01-01 |         1 |  2 | 10,20  |
+------------+-----------+----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! will take a look at the group_concat function

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to add "batch_DT" in the "group by" part also helps eliminating the wrong outputs.